# Align the views in relativelayout after enabling and disabling the textviews

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Have a relative layout with some views (textviews, edittext and button). When viewing and hiding the textview, the layout not moving up. While hiding the view (textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)) it create blank space instead of pushing the view up.

*Layout file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text1"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text2"
                android:layout_below="@id/text1"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text3"
                android:layout_below="@id/text2"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text4"
                android:layout_below="@id/text3"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text5"
                android:layout_below="@id/text4"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext1"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext2"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edittext3"
                android:padding="20dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/enable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Enable"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/disable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/enable"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="disable"/>



        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

*Activity file*

```
public class SampleTransparent extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn_enable, btn_disable;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout3);

    btn_enable = findViewById(R.id.enable);
    btn_disable = findViewById(R.id.disable);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text5);

    btn_enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    btn_disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

*Before Enabling view*

[image: Before Enabling View]

*After enabling and disabling the view*

[image: After enabling and disabling the view]

Comment: Instead of invisible try to give visibility gone to layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View.GONE` This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

`View.INVISIBLE` This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

```
btn_disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the visibility of any view to `View.INVISIBLE` just hides the view. The view is not shown but it takes up the space required by it.

You should set the visibility to `View.GONE` if you do not want it to take any space also.

Official documentation state the following:

[View.INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout
>   purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.

[View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE)

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes. Use with setVisibility(int) and android:visibility.